# Solving equation with $\cos$ and $\sin$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$f(x) = 3\cos(x) - 9\sin(x)$

Is there an easy way to solve $f(x) = 0$?

I'm drawing a blank. It seems impossible and the solution to the question I'm trying to do skips over showing the solving.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the equation? f(x)=0?

Comment: Currently the way this is written, it doesn’t have anything that needs solving. What do you mean by “solve”?

Comment: Yes, solving for x when f(x) = 0

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=0$ means $3 \cos x = 9 \sin x$.

Now if $\cos x=0$, then $\sin x=1$ or $-1$, so values of $x$ where $\cos x=0$ are not a solution to the equation. 
Divide by $9 \cos x$ on both sides,

$\tan x = 1/3$

Now you can probably compute $\arctan(1/3)$ by a calculator and $n\pi + \arctan(1/3)$ where $n$ is an integer is the complete set of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

We have that

$$f(x)=3\cos x - 9 \sin x =0 \implies 3\cos x \cdot (1-3 \tan x)=0$$

and $\cos x=0$ is not a solution.

Comment: I should also mention the interval is [0, 2pi]. So x = pi/2,

Comment: $x=\pi/2$ is not a solution. We need that $(1-3\tan x)=0$.

Comment: Alright, so the solution is arctan(1/3) and however many solutions I want to include. But... arctan(1/3) is ~18.4, and the solutions are apparently .3217 and 3.464 .... How is this possible? The original equation is actually a derivative and I'm asked to find the points at which the derivative is zero in order to find local extrema.

Comment: Your answer is in degrees. The solution is in radians.

Comment: Wow. Of course, thanks.

Comment: @MDo Yes indeed be careful with  radians and degrees! And also recall that $\arctan$ returns values in $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

Comment: Wait... so I'm getting 0.3217 but how did they get the second solution 3.464?

Comment: $\tan x$ is positive in both quadrants $1$ and $3$, which are $\pi$ radians apart. A calculator would return only the quadrant $1$ angle since the range of $\arctan x$ is $\big(\frac{3\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\big)$.

Comment: @KM101 Usually the range of definition is $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ therefore, in that case, the calculator will return only the first quadrant and we need to add $\pi$ to obtain the solution for the third quadrant.

Comment: Yes, $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ is usually used. (I edited it because the negative sign made the formatting somewhat awkward.)

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x) = 3\cos x-9\sin x$$

$$f(x) = 0 \implies 0 = 3\cos x-9\sin x$$

$$\implies 9\sin x = 3\cos x \implies \tan x = \frac{1}{3}$$

$\tan x$ takes positive values in the first and third quadrants.

For the first quadrant,

$$x = \arctan \frac{1}{3}$$

For the third quadrant,

$$x = \pi+\arctan \frac{1}{3}$$

That is the solution for $x \in [0, 2\pi]$. For a general solution, $\tan x$ is periodic every $\pi$ radians, so for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$,

$$x = \pi n+\arctan \frac{1}{3}$$